# How to fix Laravel 8 - "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database"

Tags: mysql, laravel, migrate

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

When I do that, I get the following error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'verified_db' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = verified_db and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\Users\richa\Desktop\back-office\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:692
    688▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    689▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    690▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    691▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 692▕             throw new QueryException(
    693▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    694▕             );
    695▕         }
    696▕     }

  1   C:\Users\richa\Desktop\back-office\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'verified_db'")

  2   C:\Users\richa\Desktop\back-office\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct()
```

I already configured the .env file with my database credentials. I hope someone can assist with this.

Comment: Did you create a database called `verified_db`?

Comment: Try to clear the config cache `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: @MohamedGamalEldin I am such a NOob! Thanks bro!

Comment: You are welcome, It is okay, This happened to everyone. Which answer was correct BTW?

Comment: @MohamedGamalEldin you should create an answer and OP should accept it to help others in the future as answers are more prominent than comments.

Comment: I know it, So I asked him which one to add as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command

```
php artisan optimize
```

then run

```
php artisan serve
```

i hope you will got your solution its a cache problem .

Answer (score 0):

in  MySQL Workbench
*create a new schema in the connected server
~set [Schema Name] =  [DB_DATABASE]='your name'
run command: php artisan migrate

in  phpMyAdmin
*create a Database
~set [Database Name] =  [DB_DATABASE]='your name'
run command: php artisan migrate